# ES6 why does one have to return a promise?

Tags: javascript, angular, es6-promise

What's the difference between the two (without a return)

```
function doAsyncTask() {
  var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Async Work Complete");
      if (error) {
        reject();
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
  return promise;
}
```

The following has no "Return Promise"

```
function doAsyncTask() {
  var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Async Work Complete");
      if (error) {
        reject();
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Comment: The idea behind returning promise is that the caller can listen to change and you do not need to pass callback. If you have an async task, you need to react to change. If you do not return, how will you react?

Comment: You don't need to if you want to fire `doAsyncTask` and forget about it. Otherwise, how will you perform an action when it's done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an extension to [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60166246/3783478), you should return a promise always.

Idea is, if a function is an async function, it should provide a way to listen to changes. Its upon caller to decide if they need to react to changes.

So you can call your function as:

```
doAsyncTask().then(...);
```

or just

```
doAsyncTask();
```

But if we do not return promise, caller will never have an option to llisten.

Answer (score 3):

> ES6 why does one have to return a promise?

You don't.

> What's the difference between the two (without a return)

The difference is that one doesn't return anything.

(So you can't call `doAsyncTask` and make use of the return value).

Comment: Also, if you don't return a promise you can't await for it, or act on it when the promise is resolved.

Comment: @Terry — Yes, that all falls under "make use of"

Answer (score -3):

```
var doAsyncTask1 = function() {
   var promise = new Promise(resolve => {
        /// task that takes 5 seconds
        setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
   });
   return promise;
}

var doAsyncTask2 = function() {
   var promise = new Promise(resolve => {
        /// task that takes 5 seconds
        setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
   });
   // no return
}

await doAsyncTask1();
console.log('task complete'); // this line of code runs 5 seconds after the previous one

await doAsyncTask2(); // because you have returned nothing, 'await' does nothing
console.log('task2 not complete yet'); // this line of code runs immediately after the previous one, before the 5-second task is complete
```